# GridView and ListView in same activity? notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a gridview and a listview on the same activity, when using `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the listview to update the adapter, the gridview focused item always resets focus to the first item in the gridview. How do I stop the listview's `notifyDataSetChanged()` from "it seems", redrawing all the views on the screen and just have it update the listview separately?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the relevant code, please.

Comment: myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();